# How can I add a line break in my LINQ query?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq

I need to add a line break in my LINQ query in the "select new" section. I tried `<br />` and `"\n"` but those didn't seem to work. Any clue which command to use to get the line break?

I want to display airline image underneath the airline symbol using linq. Should I store the image path in the xml file and then query using linq? Here's the code I've got so far:

`var query = from f in XElement.Load(MapPath("flightdata2.xml")).Elements("flight")
                    select new
                    {

                        Airline = (string)f.Element("airline"),
                        DepartureAirportSymbol = (string)f.Element("departureAirportSymbol"),
                        DepartTime = (string)f.Element("departureTime"),
                        DestinationAirportSymbol = (string)f.Element("destinationAirportSymbol"),
                        ArrivalTime = (string)f.Element("arrivalTime"),
                        Stops = (int)f.Element("numberOfStops"),
                        Duration = (string)f.Element("duration"),
                        Cabin = (string)f.Element("class"),
                        Price = "$" + (Int32)f.Element("price")
                    };`

Comment: Show us the code and the error :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
 Environment.NewLine
```

For most cases it's the same as \r\n, but it's better in case it ever got run on a system that didn't use \r\n.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Environment.NewLine` is useful for inserting line breaks in strings in a typical setting. However, if you're trying to produce a line break in a web page, then you need to use `"<br />"` for an HTML line break.

Comment: Yes, lots.  Show us what you're actually doing and we'll point out one that works.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I were to guess, I'd say you probably want to flatten the results of a query for display using `String.Join(@"<br />", results);`  If so, I would explore using a bound control instead.

But then we can only guess having absolutely no information to go on...

What, ***exactly***, is happening now.  What code are you using?  What would you like to see happen?

***Edit:***  Pulling this up from comments in response to your clarification:

I would use a template field in your gridview, or use a repeater instead of a gridview. This is a presentation concern, not a data concern. Don't worry about trying to do it in LINQ.

Either a template field or a repeater will allow you to place two "fields" on top of each other on the same row for display purposes:

http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs

Comment: I'm trying to display search results using data from an XML file. I want the results to display similar to Expedia search results, which is why I was asking about line break using LINQ (and I'm binding the results to a GridView, is there a better solution?)... any clue how to do that?

Comment: If you're  binding the results to a Gridview it should handle breaking each new "row" for you.  I'm still a little hazy on exactly what you're trying to do.  A code sample would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi I edited my original post with the code. I want to be able to display airline images underneath the airline name from my xml file using linq, if that's possible.

Comment: I would use a template field in your gridview, or use a repeater instead of a gridview.  This is a presentation concern, not a data concern.  Don't worry about trying to do it in LINQ.